# React Route with ID throws 401 without nesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've got a problem with my react applciation where I am struggling with setting Route with ID params.

I went through different similar topics on StackOverFlow and it seems like the solutions are not working out for me. 
Just to clarify I am not trying to do nesting Routing. My example is to create user/:id route that would be only accessed to the User/:id Content with the ID was passed or throw 401 Error if id not passed as param

So my application currently looks like this:

```
    

    import React from "react";
    import {BrowserRouter,Switch,Route,Link} from "react-router-dom";

    const App = () =>{
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/user/1">User 1</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <hr />

            <Switch>
            
              <Route exact path="/">
                <h1>This is Welcome Page</h1>
              </Route>
              
              <Route path="/user/:userId" component={<User>} />
              
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
    }

const User= ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>User ID: {match.params.userId}</h3>
  </div>
);
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So when I am trying to go to user/1 it throws 401 error
I saw similar ways the way developers do with Nested Routes but this is not what I am trying to achieve through my application. I am trying to make the route page only for user with given ID parameter and throw 401 only if the param ID was not passed for the user route

Comment: Where is your params defined? and routing is working fine

Comment: Well I just have created it on codesandbox and for some reason it is working. 
Maybe I could snapshot my application and attach it when i get back home :)
For now it is a mystery for me why it didnt work at home and worked at codesandbox

Comment: I suppose your App function needed to export. May be . Just prediction.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-paper-q23hl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Router matchers are greedy so you need to arrange your routes from complex first to simple last.
2. Restfully, we use plural for routing so in your case, we can easily make a `/users` route to show all users and `users/:id` route to show a single user.
3. So what happens is that even if you have a url of `/users/21`, it will match to the path `/users` because it sees it first, assuming you are going to create a page for users with `/users` so you should fix that first.

```js
<Route path="/users/:id">
  <h1>This is user {params.id}</h1>
</Route>

<Route path="/users">
  <h1>This is users page</h1>
</Route>

<Route exact path="/">
  <h1>This is Welcome Page</h1>
</Route>
```

So if you're not making a `users` route and just show error if no id is given, then:

```js
<Route path="/users/:id">
  <h1>This is user {params.id}</h1>
</Route>

<Route path="/users">
  <h1>This is supposed to be an error page if no id is given when under /users</h1>
</Route>

<Route exact path="/">
  <h1>This is Welcome Page</h1>
</Route>
```

Comment: Hi Lelouch!
thanks for your quick response!
I have done what I was needed to do on CodeSandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-paper-q23hl
It worked there. ATM not available, I will review my code once i get back home and will try to figure out for my mistake. If I wont find anything I will reply to u

Comment: here updated your [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-brown-vssq0)